# Width of headings-column in CV template

Tags: width, cv

I want to modify the Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute CV template to increase the width of the column allocated to the headings on the left side of the page.

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv

Being fairly new to LaTeX, I'm having trouble figuring out what parameter controls the size of this column.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that template relies on a `res.cls`, which is old and not part of a standard TeX Live distribution. Looks like you can do `\newsectionwidth{<dimen>}` to set it to whatever you want (where `<dimen>` is a length like `3cm` or `10em`, etc.). I do not have the `.cls` file to test, however.